# Magento 2 : Shipping custom module doesn't work

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.7

I'm trying to extend shipping module of magento. I need to set shiping rate based on region.

The problem is I cannot find my shipping modules in admin panel in `Stores > Configuration` and it's not applied to storefront

here is `system.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="vendor_id" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Vendor_Name</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="zones_shipping" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Zones Fixed Shipping</label>
        <tab>vendor_id</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Module::moduleName</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Fixed Shipping</label>
            </field>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Module Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Display Text</label>
                <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title</label>
            </field>
            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Name</label>
            </field>
            <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Price</label>
                <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
            </field>
            <field id="handling_type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Source\HandlingType</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="handling_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Handling Fee</label>
                <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
            </field>
            <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Sort Order</label>
            </field>
            <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="91" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
            </field>
            <field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="92" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

here is config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
  <carriers>

    <Vendor_ModuleName>

      <active>1</active>
      <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>

      <model>\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Carrier\FixedShipping</model>

      <name>Fixed Shipping</name>

      <title>Zoned fixed shipping</title>



    </Vendor_ModuleName>

  </carriers>

</default>
```

here is my model:

```
class FixedShipping extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code = 'vendoe_moduleName';

/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isFixed = true;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
 */
protected $_rateResultFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
 */
protected $_rateMethodFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
 */
protected $customerSession;


public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
array $data = []){

    $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}

/**
* @return array
*/
public function getAllowedMethods(){

    return [$this->getCarrierCode() => __($this->getConfigData('name'))];
}

public function collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request){

    if (!$this->isActive()){

        return false;
    }



    $result->append($method);
    return $result;*/

    $item = current($request->getAllItems());
    $quote = null;
    if ($item instanceof QuoteItem){
        $quote = $item->getQuote();
    }
    if($quote){
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if($shippingAddress['region']['region_code'] == 'Cairo'){
            $shippingPrice = 20;
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        }
        elseif($shippingAddress['region']['region_code'] == 'Alexandria'){
            $shippingPrice = 34;
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        }
        //else{
            $shippingPrice = 1600;
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        //}

        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $result->append($method);
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your system.xml by following code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor_id" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Vendor_Name</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="zones_shipping" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Zones Fixed Shipping</label>
            <tab>vendor_id</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::moduleName</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Fixed Shipping</label>
                </field>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="handling_type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="7" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Source\HandlingType</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="handling_fee" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="8" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Handling Fee</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="91" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="92" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

[image: settings]

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Did you copy the code from my answer? copy again and check the screenshot.

Comment: Also remove line between <?xml version="1.0"?> and <config xmlns:xsi=" that may be cause for you

Comment: Yes, that what I did

Comment: you definitely made a mistake then, check carefully

Comment: it seems module name error. I've created new module and it works. Thank you for your help